# Convolution of symmetric arrays with NumPy: why is the result shifted?

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have two `numpy` arrays. each one containing a kernel-like function centered on zero, perfectly symmetric, both with a length of 101. When I convolve these arrays, should I expect, as a result, another array which is also centered on zero? I am using `numpy.convolve`, and I always get a resulting kernel array which is not centered on zero, which is not what I want: I need one that is also perfectly centered, not shifted.

My code is more or less like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([...])        # x-axis
array1 = np.array([...])   # Blue curve
array2 = np.array([...])   # Green curve
# All arrays are one-dimensional
conv_array = np.convolve(array1, array2, mode='same') # Red curve
conv_array /= max(conv_array) # Normalization

plt.plot(x, array1)
plt.plot(x, array2)
plt.plot(x, conv_array)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot of the curves is this:
[image: Blue curve = array1, green curve = array2, red curve = convolution result]

What do I do to obtain a not-shifted convolved array?

Comment: Some ideas. (1) Put your actual numbers in your question so others can try it. (2) Is it possible that numpy.convolve wants the length to be a power of 2? I don't know. (3) The artifact in the red curve between 20 and 30 is strange/interesting/probably relevant in some way. (4) The left end of convolution of two arrays is going to be left(a) + left(b), so you'll need to take that into account when you plot the result. (The separation from one point to the next is the same as for a and b.) There are length(a) + length(b) - 1 elements. (5) Use Octave/Matlab for comparison via `conv`.

Comment: The artifact in the red curve is a boundary artifact, which is expected. I think the problem is what MSeifert pointed out in their answer.

Comment: @RobertDodier : (1) Agree (2) No, it's not FFT (3) that's a boundary effect (4) not true, since he uses ``mode='same'`` then the result has the length ``max(len(array1), len(array2))`` (5) Not sure how that helps, the problem is that convolution has different definitions and one needs to know which is used and comparing it to another one could be more confusing if it doesn't use the same definition.

Comment: @MSeifert Re (5): I agree that it's importance to be careful about the definition of the convolution. I see the numpy.convolve documentation leaves something to be desired in that respect -- the formula given doesn't say what to do for finite sequences (as all actual inputs must be), and it doesn't state exactly which elements are returned for 'same' and 'valid'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple alternative is to use `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d` instead of `numpy.convolve`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.modeling import models

# Create a model
x = np.arange(101) - 50       # x-axis
g1 = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=2, mean=0, stddev=4)
g2 = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=3, mean=0, stddev=3)
array1 = g1(x)
array2 = 1 - g2(x)

from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d

conv_array2 = convolve1d(array1, array2)
conv_array2 /= conv_array2.max()

# One can also use numpy convolve here
conv_array = np.convolve(array1, array2, mode='same') # Red curve
conv_array /= max(conv_array) # Normalization

plt.plot(x, array1)
plt.plot(x, array2)
plt.plot(x, conv_array) # Is centered on 0
plt.plot(x, conv_array2) # Is centered on 0
plt.show()
```

I guess the problem is that your arrays are not exactly centered on 0. (So `x[50] != 0`). And numpy flips the kernel before convolution and therefore you get a shift. Notice if you try my example the `numpy.convolve` result is also perfectly centered on 0 but I made sure `array1` and `array2` were centered on 0. From your plot I guess that `-22<x<27` (which is not centered)

The reason why I recommend `scipy` is because I also had a similar problem :-) They just use different definitions: [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) and [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d.html) notice the different signs of the kernel-index.

Comment: Yes, after posting the question, I realized that the fact that the arrays themselves are shifted (although equally) could be the problem. I'll try your solution soon.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was my data, and I was mistaken in thinking they were symmetric. Also, MSeifert's suggestion fixed the boundary effect that could bring some unpleasantries.

Answer (score 0):

I fear this is a mathematical question on convolution, which I cannot answer.  However if you simply wish to center the convolved array on zero (its minima) then the following will provide a 'quick fix':

```
plt.plot(x + x[np.argmin(conv_array[:conv_array.shape[0]*3/4)]],conv_array)
```